# Push notification not showing sometimes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, push

I don't know why but sometimes I don't receive push notifications (on iOS). The only way I found to receive them is to do the following steps:

- Removing app from device
- Removing pods and redo a pod install
- Clearing Derived Data
- Cleaning project
- Reinstalling application with XCode (using development certificate)

I checked all the logs from my server (and APN) and everything seems to be OK.
Since I receive sometimes push (and I do not change code to fix it when it does not work), my code seems to be valid.

FYI, Push notification is enabled in Capabilities tab.

I'm on XCode 8 and iOS from 8 to 10 and code is written in Objective-C.

Does anyone knows the origin of this stange bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is OS bug. Please try by restarting your device.
https://twitter.com/yogye7/status/781340933228945408

Comment: Still not working. Tried update to last iOS version and restart and still having the problem.

Comment: Try by Switch OFF and ON the notification in settings app

Answer (score 0):

Ref this link [Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

**Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS:**
The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day
   or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.